# Adding subdomain for different user types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, subdomain

I am pretty new to Rails and most of my knowledge depends on tutorials :)

So, I followed this http://www.railstutorial.org tutorial and created really good site but now I run into a problem. For my users I have a special column in my database which shows which type of user he is. For example I have column 'student' which is 'true' if user is student and 'false' if he's not.

Now I would like to create a subdomain for students. So, when student wants to sign up or sign in he would be transferred to www.student.mysite.com instead of www.mysite.com.

How can I accomplish that?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to do this, specifically you'll be interested in looking up [`multi-tenancy`](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Multitenancy) in respect to rails

--

**Multi Tenancy**

Whilst multi tenancy is typically the definition of having multiple databases / assets (one for each user), however, as it's ridiculously difficult to get this working in rails (something we're currently working on), you can use the principle with a single stack of data

There are several tutorials on how to achieve this with Rails here:

> - [Basecamp-style subdomains by DHH](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/1512-how-to-do-basecamp-style-subdomains-in-rails) (although looks like the post is down)
> - [Multitenancy with PostgreSQL (Railscasts)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/389-multitenancy-with-postgresql?view=comments)
> - [Apartment Gem (achieving multi tenancy on Rails)](https://github.com/influitive/apartment)

Although this is not directly related to your question, most of the "multi tenancy" questions
are typically based on "how do I create different subdomains for my users"

--

**Subdomains**

The basis of subdomains on Rails is to capture the request, and route it to the correct controller. We've managed to achieve that using the following setup:

```
#config/routes.rb
constraints Subdomain do #-> lib/subdomain.rb & http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

    #Account
    namespace :accounts, path: "" do #=> http://[account].domain.com/....

        #Index
        root to: "application#show"

    end
end

#lib/subdomain.rb
class Subdomain
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.present? && request.subdomain != 'www'
  end
end
```

This will give you the ability to do the following:

```
#app/controllers/accounts/application_controller.rb
class Account::ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_action :set_account

   def show
      #@account set before_action. If not found, raises "not found" exception ;)
   end

   private

   #Params from Subdomain
   def set_account
        params[:id] ||= request.subdomains.first unless request.subdomains.blank?
        @account = Account.find params[:id]
   end
end
```

Ideally, we'd love to handle this in the middleware, but as it stands, this is what we've got!

This will give you the ability to call the data you need from the `@account` variable:

```
#app/views/accounts/application/show.html.erb
<%= @account.name %>
```

Comment: Thank you. +1 but I still don't quite understand how to redirect user to specific domain depending on his profile. So, if he is a student, I want redirect to student.myapp.com.